# Using 'bcp' sql server connection failed, Unable to invoke odbc.ini dns

Tags: sql-server, redhat, database, unixodbc

I'm new to MS SQL server, doing tryouts to connect to MS-SQL Server through Linux system.
For this I had installed [odbc driver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt703139.aspx) & configured odbc.ini.

By using sqlcmd, I'm able to connect to SQL server. Following command used:

`sqlcmd -D -U$DBUSER -P$DBPASSWD -S$SERVER`

But I'm trying to use bcp for bulk copy which did not work.
Command:

`bcp $DBNAME.dbo.$TABLE1 out $FILE1 -c -m 100 -e $TABLE1.out.bcperr -U$DBUSER -P$DBPASSWD -S$SERVER`

But this command gives error

`CTLIB Message:  - L6/O8/S5/N3/5/0:
ct_connect(): directory service layer: internal directory control layer error: Requested server name not found`

I had tried to add `-D` option to bcp but it gives error, invalid option -D.
How I can use bcp so that, it will work same as sqlcmd?

Comment: **1.** are you sure `$FILE1` is accessible however you have that variable resolving from the SQL Server itself? What is the value of `$FILE1`? Is needs to be access from the SQL Server level and not a local path on the machine when you run the command so user a network location or a path local on the SQL Server which has access. **2.** `-e` is supposed to go to a FILE (not a table) that is again accessible from the SQL Server level and not the local machine you are running the BCP from I thought. These are quick thoughts so give a try and please report back if that helps you any.

Comment: Thank you for comment 1. `$FILE` is output datafile, `out` operation performing using `bcp` 2. Sorry for confusion of `$TABLE` with -e, I'm using `$TABLE` variable along with file name just for my understanding. If table name is _abc_ then error file will be _abc.out.bcperr_.